# Como obter mais de um período a partir de duas datas com C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Preciso obter dois períodos distintos a partir de duas datas. A contagem de um período é considerada somente fora do intervalo e a outra somente quando estiver dentro do intervalo. Estou achando complicado fazer apenas com as estruturas do c#. É viável fazer estes cálculos sem o auxilio de uma extensão ?

Por exemplo:

Começa as 3hrs e vai até as 6hrs para a contagem do período dentro do intervalo, depois começa a contar o período fora do intervalo só até as 23hrs, depois retoma a contagem do período dentro do intervalo até as 6hrs e volta a contar o período fora do intervalo até as 23hrs novamente, e assim por diante.

```
DateTime dataInicial = new DateTime(2022, 03, 01, 3, 0, 0); //01/03/22 03:00
DateTime dataFinal= new DateTime(2022, 03, 03, 10, 0, 0); //03/03/22 10:00
```

Intervalo de tempo entre essas data:

```
TimeSpan inicioIntervalo = TimeSpan.FromHours(23);
TimeSpan fimIntervalo = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);
```

Resultado esperado:

Período total = 2 dias e 7 horas

Período fora do intervalo = 38 horas

Período dentro do intervalo = 17 horas

Por enquanto consegui alguns resultados mas não funciona para o exemplo acima, fiz desta forma:

```
TimeSpan periodoTotal = dataFinal - dataInicial;
DateTime intervaloFim = dataFinal.Date.Add(fimIntervalo);
DateTime intervaloInicio = dataFinal.Date.AddDays(-1).Add(inicioIntervalo);

var periodoForaDoIntervalo = (dataFinal > intervaloFim ? TimeSpan.FromTicks(Math.Abs(dataFinal.Ticks - intervaloFim.Ticks)) : TimeSpan.Zero)
                    + (dataInicial < intervaloInicio ? TimeSpan.FromTicks(Math.Abs(dataInicial.Ticks - intervaloInicio.Ticks)) : TimeSpan.Zero);

TimeSpan periodoDentroDoIntervalo = periodoTotal - periodoForaDoIntervalo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, você tem que entender a diferença entre horas e durações:

- um horário representa um momento específico do dia. Ex: a reunião será às duas horas da tarde (diz exatamente em qual momento do dia será a reunião)
- uma duração representa uma quantidade de tempo. Ex: a reunião durou duas horas (eu não disse que horas ela começou ou terminou, só disse quanto tempo ela durou)

O que pode confundir é que tanto horários quanto durações usam as mesmas palavras (horas, minutos e segundos), e muitas vezes são escritos do mesmo jeito ("11:00" pode ser tanto 11 da manhã quanto uma duração de 11 horas). Mas cada um representa um conceito diferente.

No caso do C#, um `DateTime` representa uma data e hora, enquanto um `TimeSpan` representa uma duração. Como 23h e 06h são horários (momentos específicos do dia), não creio que seja o mais adequado usar um `TimeSpan` para representar esses horários, pois você também tem que considerar cada dia contido no intervalo.

O `TimeSpan` é adequado para guardar as durações, mas para manipular as datas (setar o horário, etc), use o `DateTime` mesmo.

---

Dito isso, a ideia básica é pegar o horário inicial e final de cada dia, e ver se eles se encaixam no intervalo total.

No seu caso, você começa em 01/03/22 às 03:00, mas como o horário inicial é 23h, então eu considero que a contagem começou às 23h do dia anterior, e terminou às 6h do dia 01/03.

Depois eu avanço para 23h do dia 01/03, até as 6h do dia 02, e assim por diante, até chegar no dia 03/03/22 às 10:00. E neste processo todo eu vou guardando a duração em um `TimeSpan`, e atualizando de acordo.

Também tenho que descontar as horas do início e final, caso não comece às 23h nem termine às 6h. Ficaria assim:

```cs
int horaInicial = 23, horaFinal = 6;
DateTime dataInicial = new DateTime(2022, 03, 01, 3, 0, 0); //01/03/22 03:00
DateTime dataFinal = new DateTime(2022, 03, 03, 10, 0, 0); //03/03/22 10:00

TimeSpan dentroIntervalo = TimeSpan.Zero;
// começa pegando a data inicial e mudando o horário para 23h
// no caso, Date pega somente a data - então soma-se 23 horas para obter esta data às 23h
DateTime inicioIntervalo = dataInicial.Date.AddHours(horaInicial);
// verifica se precisa ajustar para 23h do dia anterior
if (inicioIntervalo > dataInicial)
{
    inicioIntervalo = inicioIntervalo.AddDays(-1);
}
// já o fim seria o mesmo dia às 6h
DateTime fimIntervalo = dataInicial.Date.AddHours(horaFinal);

// desconta a diferença do início, caso 23h seja antes da data inicial
if (inicioIntervalo < dataInicial)
{
    dentroIntervalo -= dataInicial - inicioIntervalo;
}
while (fimIntervalo <= dataFinal)
{
    dentroIntervalo += fimIntervalo - inicioIntervalo;
    fimIntervalo = fimIntervalo.AddDays(1);
    inicioIntervalo = inicioIntervalo.AddDays(1);
}
// desconta a diferença do final, caso seja depois das 6h do último dia
if (fimIntervalo < dataFinal)
{
    dentroIntervalo -= dataFinal - fimIntervalo;
}

// tendo o total dentro do intervalo, basta subtrair do total geral
TimeSpan total = dataFinal - dataInicial;
TimeSpan foraIntervalo = total - dentroIntervalo;
Console.WriteLine($"Período total: {total}");
Console.WriteLine($"Período fora do intervalo: {foraIntervalo}");
Console.WriteLine($"Período dentro do intervalo: {dentroIntervalo}");
```

Quanto a formatar o `TimeSpan`, não está claro o formato que deve ser usado. O período total você quer que seja "2 dias e 7 horas", mas o período fora do intervalo deve ser "38 horas" - **por que não "1 dia e 14 horas"?**

Uma forma simples seria:

```cs
static string Format(TimeSpan ts)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int total = (int) ts.TotalMinutes;
    if (total > 1440)
    {
        sb.Append(total / 1440).Append(" dias");
        total %= 1440;
    }
    if (total > 60)
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
          sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(total / 60).Append(" horas");
        total %= 60;
    }
    if (total > 0)
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
          sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(total).Append(" minutos");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

//....
// E ao final do cálculo:
Console.WriteLine($"Período total: {Format(total)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Período fora do intervalo: {Format(foraIntervalo)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Período dentro do intervalo: {Format(dentroIntervalo)}");
```

Mas fica um pouco diferente do que você quer:

```
Período total: 2 dias, 7 horas
Período fora do intervalo: 1 dias, 14 horas
Período dentro do intervalo: 17 horas
```

De qualquer forma, aí basta adaptar para o que você precisa. Você pode incrementar se quiser, usando [alguma dessas opções](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16689468), por exemplo.